dividing aggregate expressions (Count / Count) results to zoro, no matter what
here's a code snippet of the problem

#multiplication works fine
drivers.annotate(
            completed_orders_percentage=( Count('orders', filter=Q(orders__rejected=False), distinct=True) * Count('orders', distinct=True) ) * 100 ,
        )

#addition works fine
drivers.annotate(
            completed_orders_percentage=( Count('orders', filter=Q(orders__rejected=False), distinct=True) + Count('orders', distinct=True) ) * 100 ,
        )

#subtraction works fine
drivers.annotate(
            completed_orders_percentage=( Count('orders', filter=Q(orders__rejected=False), distinct=True) -  Count('orders', distinct=True) ) * 100 ,
        )

#diving not working (returns 0)
drivers.annotate(
            completed_orders_percentage=( Count('orders', filter=Q(orders__rejected=False), distinct=True) / Count('orders', distinct=True) ) * 100 ,
        )

i couldnt find anything useful in the docs, i thought that it might be due to type of the return so i tried to wrappe it in ExeprisionWrapper with output_field=FloatField() but still the same!

Try completed_orders_percentage=100 * Count('orders', filter=Q(orders__rejected=False), distinct=True) / Count('orders', distinct=True), unless you need float percentages.

This is an integer division, so a percentage will indeed never work.

You are performing integer division, so the result gets truncated towards zero.
You can move the multiplication to the front, which will thus prevent such rounding error:
drivers.annotate(
    completed_orders_percentage=100
    * Count('orders', filter=Q(orders__rejected=False), distinct=True)
    / Count('orders', distinct=True),
)

that worked, is there any way to make Count return float? in C we can just cast the integer to a float, is that possible here?

@bakboki: use Cast: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast
